# Retrieving value from spinner with custom enum

Tags: android, enums, spinner

I have a custom enum class:

```
public static enum Frequency_Unit{
    MINUTES("Minutes", 0),
    HOURS("Hours", 1),
    DAYS("Days", 2),
    WEEKS("Weeks", 3),
    MONTHS("Months", 4),
    YEARS("Years", 5);

    private String stringValue;
    private int intValue;
    private Frequency_Unit(String toString, int value) {
        this.stringValue = toString;
        this.intValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

I used it to set up a spinner:

```
spinner_frequency = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_repeat_frequency);
spinner_frequency.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Constants.Frequency_Unit>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Constants.Frequency_Unit.values()));
```

Now I want to retrieve the numerical value with onItemSelectedListener (i.e. 1 if the user selects "Hours"):

```
spinner_frequency.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinner_frequency_listener);
```

But within the Listener itself I don't know how to retrieve that value.

```
OnItemSelectedListener spinner_frequency_listener = new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{       
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        if (parent.getChildCount() > 0){
            int repeat_frequency = //**VALUE SHOULD BE HERE**
        }
    }


    // Default line, when nothing is selected
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {    

    }
};
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it simple by calling as below:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Frequency_Unit freq = (Frequency_Unit) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

    //do whatever with 'freq'
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Just had to add some getters to the Frequency_Unit class and then use `repeat_frequency = freq.getIntValue();`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                Beantype genreBean = (Beantype ) parent
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
}
```